# Reading a file and creating objects from the information

Tags: java, java-io

I have two files and I want to individually read them then use the the first file to create 5 objects and then use the second file to add the parameters to be passed to a constructor, question is is I am not quite sure how to do that.

What I wanted to do was to loop the `hasNextLine` and assign the next line to a string and have an object created from that string name, then passing variables in the same way but I see that may not be possible in Java. If it isn't what is another way I could approach this?

Well I was trying to do something like this

```
   while(salesPersonScanner.hasNextLine()){
   String personName = salesPersonScanner.nextLine();
    SalesPerson personName = new SalesPerson();

    }
```

Comment: What code did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `BufferedReader` to iterate over lines:

```
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file"));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // Create your object from the string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. You can read all of the required parameters from files and then pass them all to the constructor to create a new object.
2. You can create an object with your constructor and use setters to set each of the instance variables.

I personally suggest the first approach unless you have to set lots of variables.